# Style a div with 3 Colors dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

My requirement is I have to style a div dynamically with 3 colors. 
I have done it with random colors applying this code

```
function randomColors() {

var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
}
return color;
```

}

I have to repeat 3 Colors only, and that is going to be in a loop dynamically ! How can i do that?

I want only these 3 colors #09c5f9, #05f6d5, #a42cff dynamically set.

```
for(i=1; i <= pmap; i++){
      $("#thumbnail"+i).css("background-color",randomColors());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of two ways to do it.

1) The easiest if you're using jQuery (and In my opinion the correct way to do it) is to declare three classes and swap them using jQuery.

The CSS:

```
.teal{
    background-color: #09c5f9;
}
.emerald{
    background-color: #05f6d5;
}
.purple{
    background-color: #a42cff;
}
```

and the javascript:

```
$("#some-element").removeClass("teal emerald").addClass("purple");
$("#some-element").removeClass("teal purple").addClass("emerald");
$("#some-element").removeClass("purple emerald").addClass("teal");
```

2) This way uses bare-metal JS and also uses the same programming style you used in the original post.

```
var colors = ["#09c5f9", "#05f6d5", "#a42cff"];

function getColor(colorNumber){
    return colors[colorNumber];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function randomColors() {
var letters = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split('');
var color = '#';
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++ ) {
    color += letters[Math.round(Math.random() * 15)];
}
return color;
}
```

you can see Demo, in which background-color of div will set randomly.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MWdA8/3/)

you can take hint from there.